# Easiest way to make .NET DLL visible to COM?

Tags: .net, dll, wrapper, com-interop, regasm

I have a proprietary `.NET` DLL which I would like to use in a `COM` client.

Currently when I use `regasm` it says: `warning RA0000 : No types were registered`

Since I don't have the source code I can't set the classes to `ComVisible` or whatever else is required.

How can I **easily** make this DLL visible to `COM`?

Comment: You are expecting a software vendor to recompile DLLs for me at my request?

Comment: No, I'd expect a software vendor to give you quote for the required work.  This is the way the world works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a "COM callable wrapper". Here are a few links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32754

Some of these are quite old, but I imagine the principles have remained the same.

Edit: someone seems to have written a generic wrapper:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113720/Universal-COM-Callable-Wrapper